# Propagate dates pandas and interpolate

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

We have some ready available sales data for certain periods, like 1week, 1month...1year:

```
time_pillars = pd.Series(['1W', '1M', '3M', '1Y'])
sales = pd.Series([4.75, 5.00, 5.10, 5.75])
data = {'time_pillar': time_pillars, 'sales': sales}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to do two operations. 
Firstly, create a new column of date type, df['date'], that corresponds to the actual date of 1week, 1month..1year from now.

Then, I'd like to create another column df['days_from_now'], taking how many days are on these pillars (1week would be 7days, 1month would be around 30days..1year around 365days).

The goal of this is then to use any day as input for a a simple linear_interpolation_method() to obtain sales data for any given day (eg, what are sales for 4Octobober2018?  ---> We would interpolate between 3months  and 1year). 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean regarding your interpolation, but here is a way to make your dataframe in `pandas` (starting from your original `df` you provided in your post):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def create_dates(df):
    df['date'] = [i.date() for i in 
                   [d+delt for d,delt in zip([datetime.now()] * 4 , 
                   [relativedelta(weeks=1), relativedelta(months=1), 
                       relativedelta(months=3), relativedelta(years=1)])]]
    df['days_from_now'] = df['date'] - datetime.now().date()
    return df

create_dates(df)

   sales time_pillar        date days_from_now
0   4.75          1W  2018-04-11        7 days
1   5.00          1M  2018-05-04       30 days
2   5.10          3M  2018-07-04       91 days
3   5.75          1Y  2019-04-04      365 days
```

I wrapped it in a function, so that you can call it on any given day and get your results for 1 week, 3 weeks, etc. from that exact day.

Note: if you want your `days_from_now` to simply be an integer of the number of days, use `df['days_from_now'] = [i.days for i in df['date'] - datetime.now().date()]` in the function, instead of `df['days_from_now'] = df['date'] - datetime.now().date()`

**Explanation:**

```
df['date'] = [i.date() for i in 
               [d+delt for d,delt in zip([datetime.now()] * 4 , 
               [relativedelta(weeks=1), relativedelta(months=1), 
                   relativedelta(months=3), relativedelta(years=1)])]]
```

Takes a list of the date today (`datetime.now()`) repeated 4 times, and adds a `relativedelta` (a time difference) of 1 week, 1 month, 3 months, and 1 year, respectively, extracts the date (`i.date() for ...`), finally creating a new column using the resulting list.

```
df['days_from_now'] = df['date'] - datetime.now().date()
```

is much more straightforward, it simply subtracts those new dates that you got above from the date today. The result is a timedelta object, which `pandas` conveniently formats as "`n days`".